# Software to copy some strings of text and paste them in succession

Tags: string, copy, paste, shortcut

I'd like to know if there is such a software (on either windows or linux) that allows to copy several strings of text but then paste them one after another.

Example: I copy string A which is '000' then copy string B which is 'BBB' then copy string C which is '111'.
Then I want to just hit the Ctrl+V combo 3 times in a row and the first time string A should be pasted, then the 2nd time string B will be pasted and so on.

Thank you

Comment: Looks like you're after some macro-recorder.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if any programs in particular that will enable this throughout all of Windows or Linux, but individual programs have this feature enabled.

For example if you are using Visual Studio for development, you can paste by pressing Ctrl+Shift+V and it will rotate through the most recent things you copied. VS is the only software I know of that does this, but there are likely others as well.